# Route works locally, but fails on production

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, routes

I have a static route which basically maps url pattern to a specific controller action.

```
routes.MapRoute(
name: "StaticRoute1", url: "getxml", defaults: new { Controller = "XmlData", Action = GetXml" });
```

So the url like:

```
www.example.com/getxml?id=1&size=100
```

Should call the XmlDataController GetXml method.

It works locally fine, but in production I get:

No route in the route table matches the supplied values.

```
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: No route in the route table matches the supplied values.
```

How can I diagnose this issue?

Comment: You don't have any rewrite rules setup on your production server by any chance?

Comment: no, one difference is that there is a subdomain ie. qa.example.com and locally it was like http://localhost:3424/getxml?...

Comment: How is the url being created/generated?

Answer (score -2):

You've defined your URL mapping incorrectly.  In it's current state, you're nothing mapping id nor size to anything.  You need to update your URL to actually map to the parameters of your controller.  Update the URL to something like

Try something like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
   name: "StaticRoute1",
   url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}/{size}",
   defaults: new { controller = "myController", action = "getxml", id = 1, size = 200 }
);
```

Comment: The url pattern isn't controller/action/id/size, the url is:  www.example.com/getxml?userid=12&....

Comment: @user1361315 thanks, feel free to properly update the routing map to your desired pattern.  No need to downvote my answer when I pointed out that your original routing map doesn't actually map to anything.

Comment: It works locally though?   And I appreciate your response and I wasn't the person who downvoted!